# How to store the values of two lists in a single dictionary where values of first list is a key and the values of second list are attributes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
road= []
distance=[]
i= input ('THE NUMBER OF NODES TO TEST')
for i in range(0,i):
    a = input(' THE NODE NUMBER \n')
    b= input ('ENTER NODE VALUE \n')

    road.append(a)
    distance.append(b)  
    print 'THE NODES AND RESPECTIVE VALUES ARE'
    print "NODES:  \t | \t VALUES:\n " ,words, distance
```

In above python sample code road and distance are two lists which will store the value input by the user. Now I want to add those data in a dictionary where `road[0]:distance[0], road[1]: distance[1]` and so on. i.e. The values inserted in the list 'road' and 'distance' should be included in a new dictionary say 'map'which is somehow like this map={"road":"distance"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-dict) built-in functions.

```
dict(zip(road,distance))
```

**Example:**

```
>>> road = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> distance = [1,2]
>>> dict(zip(road,distance))
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

Comment: use ordereddict if necessary `OrderedDict(zip(road,distance))`

Answer (score 2):

using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) will save your time.

But simple code is:

```
road = [1,2,3,4,5]
distance = [100,150,120,150,200]
dict = {}
for i in range(0, len(road)):
    dict[road[i]] = distance[i]
```